# ValueError: The environment is of type <class '__main__.StockTradingEnvironment'>, not a Gymnasium environment

Tags: python-3.x, machine-learning, deep-learning, reinforcement-learning, openai-gym

When running the code
`env = DummyVecEnv([lambda: StockTradingEnvironment(stock_data)])`, it provides

`ValueError: The environment is of type <class '__main__.StockTradingEnvironment'>, not a Gymnasium environment. In this case, we expect OpenAI Gym to be installed and the environment to be an OpenAI Gym environment.`

I have already imported the necessary libraries like the following.

```
import yfinance as yf
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from stable_baselines3 import DQN
from stable_baselines3.common.vec_env import DummyVecEnv
from gym import spaces
```

How to resolve this error?

Comment: Could you share the class definition for `StockTradingEnvironment` and what is value assigned to variable `stock_data`?